# Dealer not reestablishing connection in ZeroMQ

Tags: .net, qt, zeromq

I have a number of applications using ZeroMq and their respective wrappers (.Net/QT)

I am using a dealer/router pattern and have the following issue.

Device A (.net) is the Router, Device B & C (QT) are Dealers.  When device B or C does not gracefully close the TCP connection, any subsequent attempts to make a ZeroMQ connection fail.

What is the best practice for releasing ZeroMq connections?  Is this internal to the API?

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of question about using ZeroMQ, the best way to help others help you is to write a minimal test case they can use to reproduce the problem you're seeing. Otherwise, all we can do is answer in possibles and maybes.

What does "fail" mean in this case? Who is binding, who is connecting?

When making a minimal test case, use the basic C API so that we can exclude any language binding issues.

Cheers

Comment: Will try to get an example together to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I'm using pyzmq. if one of the client dealers supplying its own identity (Merbs'B and C) is disconnected from the server Router (A),  then brought back up, the Router does not appear to update its record of where to find the Identity despite the new connection. Is this expected functionality?

Comment: From router.cpp:identify_peer() - 

 //  Ignore peers with duplicate ID.
            if (it != outpipes.end ())
                return false;

It appears that this is indeed the case - Pieter, do you think making it a socket option (or even the default) of whether to update the pipe to the latest connection using a specific identity would be worthwhile?